# Incorrect count of "featured" questions

Tags: support, bounty

Just today I decide to place a bounty on [an old question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3075/250), and notice that the count doesn't get incremented.

Is this some form of caching, i.e by design? Or is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: OK the count is 4 now, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but the tab looks right now, so I'd guess it's caching:

[image: Screenshot of the featured tab]